# Java DirContext change DN format

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have value of DN `cn=tuser01,ou=users,o=data` Can I change this to below format

```
\VAULT\data\users\tuser01
```

I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't redefine X.500 just to suit yourself.